# Why does my program crash when implementing an indirect jump?

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, x86

I want to do an instant jump (to improve performance) instead of calling a new function or making a jump table. I have no idea why this code works on my compiler but it cannot jump properly :

```
__asm mov eax, __cmd
__asm jmp eax //Crash!

__cmd :
//Some code
```

I tried the second method, it also compiles but doesn't work :

```
int address = 10;
__asm jmp (__cmd + address) //Crash!

__cmd :
var += value;return;
var -= value;return;
var *= value;return;
var /= value;return;
var %= value;return;
```

But, it only works with constants :

```
__asm jmp (__cmd + 10) //works
```

Why does my program crash when implementing an indirect jump? And is there anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you need to write `mov eax, offset __cmd`? I strongly advise against doing what you're doing. You're most likely optimizing the wrong thing and only getting into much trouble.

Comment: @Alexey Frunze I'm trying my best to improve performance at all costs, yeah implementing it is quite dangerous but it's not the wrong thing. Because at least I have to handle my 19 operators total. And indeed it reduced about 1/8 my execution time. :)

Comment: Unless you write the target code in asm yourself, a computed goto is insane.  You can't know what the compiler is going to emit at different optimization levels.  Also, assuming + and - are most frequent, checking for them first and branchlessly handling the sign might be your best bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, I found the answer:

```
mov eax, offset __cmd
```

Now I'm able to implement indirectly jumps.